# What is the default background color for a TabItem?

Tags: wpf

I'm attempting to match another element to the TabItem and need the color or SystemColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the default `TabControl` and `TabItem` template which shows the colors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035(v=vs.95).aspx

To ensure you match the exact color with minimal effort, you could simply use a binding:

```
<MyControl Background="{Binding ElementName=MyTabElement, Path=Background}" />
```